# How to show a secondary view before the main view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, xib

I'm wanting to have my app (on launch) load a view that I have created over the top of the original view, then when a button is clicked the top view will disappear and show the main view underneath.  I know this is terribly simple, but how would I do this?  Maybe push the view in `viewDidLoad`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be incredibly simple. When the user clicks the button, just do this

```
secondViewController.view.hidden = YES;
```

Just add the two views in your delegate, and do that in your delegate.

If you prefer, just do it "in" secondViewController!  self.view.hidden = YES;

It sounds like you're just doing something simple ...... no need to bother with a view controller.

You ask how to display the second view, just like this ..

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)applic`ation
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
        {
        [window addSubview:yourMainView.view];
        [window addSubview:theTemporaryView.view]; // it goes on top

        [window makeKeyAndVisible];

        application.idleTimerDisabled = YES;
        return YES;
        }
-(BOOL)eliminateTempView // example, when the user clicks on the button
        {
        theTemporaryView.view.hidden = YES;
        [theTemporaryView release];
        }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, it is incredibly simple.  Just like an "Accept the terms" kind of thing.  How would I display the view using this method, though?

Comment: Yes it that seems like it would work perfectly.  When I enter the code in, however, it gives me no warnings but it does not show the view.  Maybe I'm doing it wrong?  What I did is create a "firstLaunch" object named "theLaunch". (firstLaunch is the view I want over the main view)  Then I did your code substituting "the TemporaryView" for "theLaunch".  It builds and runs successfully, but the view is not shown. Any ideas?

Comment: Oops, never mind.  I found that if I do `[firstLaunch *theLaunch = [[firstLaunch alloc] init];`, then use that it works just fine.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Oh one more question.  How would I call "eliminateTempView" from my other view?

Comment: Oh never mind, I just did `self.view.hidden = YES;` in my temporary view and all is well. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a navigation controller

```
MyViewController *myView = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navControl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myView];
My2ndView *secondView = ....
[navControl pushViewController:secondView animated:NO];
[window addSubView:navControl.view]
```

Comment: note: you can hide the top nav bar item so its transparent, just to manage your views

Comment: What would `window` be in this case?  Also, would this go in my delegate, and if so, why is it giving me an error saying "UIWindow may not respond to '-addSubView:'"?

Comment: Well, looks like that error gets removed if I change "addSubView" to "addSubview".

Comment: Yeah sorry was doing that from memory ;)